# Call create action from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I would like to create a booking from `bookings#new` and `rooms#show`. When I try to create it from `bookings#new` it works, but when try to create it from `rooms#show` it shows me the error:

> 1 error prohibited this booking from being saved, room must exist.

Here is the code I'm using:

BookingsController:

```
def create
  if @room          
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
    @booking = @room.bookings.create(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to room_path(@room)
    else
      render :new
    end        
  else 
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

views/rooms/show.html.erb

```
<h2>book this room:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [ @room, @room.bookings.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :traveller %>
    <%= form.text_field :traveller %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= form.label :startfrom %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :startfrom %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :endsat %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :endsat %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :bookingref %>
    <%= form.text_field :bookingref %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have `params[:room_id]` in that case? Or why do you check for `@room` before you set it?

Comment: here is a good article about how to debug your application in development http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: I think could be related with the `belongs_to` association. Please post your `Room` and `Booking` models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is inside if-else in the controller. You're checking `@room` before you define it, so it is always nil. It should be:

```
def create
  # use find_by here, otherwise you get RecordNotFound error
  @room = Room.find_by(id: params[:room_id])
    if @room
      # use build, because create saves the instance
      @booking = @room.bookings.build(booking_params)
      if @booking.save
        redirect_to room_path(@room)
      else
        # I suppose you don't want render bookings/new view here
        render 'books/show'
      end
    else 
      @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        # redirect and render logic goes here. BTW, do you really need json response format?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, define in rooms#show action

```
@booking = @room.bookings.build
```

and use the instance in the form to correctly display validation errors

```
form_with(model: [@room, @booking], local: true) do |form|
```

Comment: @Blueash, happy to help you!